# Javascript match between ' and ') not working

Tags: javascript, regex, expression, match

Im trying to get the string out of a function i created.

I want to get the string between **'** and **')**

Unformated String

```
('parameter 1','parameter 2 it's harder');
```

I want to get the following string

```
parameter 2 it's harder
```

Im using a match expression in javascript but i cant get the parameter out correctly

Here are the expressions ive tried:

**gets characters between ' and '**

```
string1.match(/\(([^()]+)\)/g)
```

**gets characters between ( and )**

```
string1.match(/,'([^']+)'/)
```

Does anyone know what patter to use to get the characters between ' and ')

Comment: Will there always be two strings in the parenthesis?

Comment: Is second parameter a true one? Single quote within value is not escaped.

Comment: This is incorrect syntax, not really parsable since: (START)'parameter 2 it'(STOP)s harder', you have a ' inside the string

Comment: You will always have this issue if you have non-escaped `'` in your parameters.

Comment: Is this what you want? http://regex101.com/r/nR9yJ9/1

Comment: get everything between `('` and `')` then split your string by the index of `','` using `substr`

Comment: why the thumbs down, thanks for all the answers guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've a syntactical error within second given parameter! However - *overlooking this error* - you can get the result with this regex:

```
'([^,]+)(?='\))
```

Look for the first capturing group. **[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/dY5sE8/1)**

Answer (score 0):

In

```
parameter 2 it's harder
```

the apostrophe is un-escaped.  Escape the string using `\'` and then it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This works for your exact example: `/','(.*?)'\)/`.

... however, you should really fix your source formatting, as suggested in the comments.  You'll have parsing nightmares with that.